# Why's my post request working in Postman but not on the browser even though I'm doing it sort of similarly?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

I have no idea why this post request doesn't work in the browser in terms of the `file_path`, `user_id` and `email` being stored in the database.

In my logs I'm getting this error:  `ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`

But it works totally fine in Postman.  First I login using endpoint below, then I choose a file and finally, upload using another endpoint.  The file_path`,` user_id`and`email` get stored in the database successfully using Postman.

When the user logs in (via browser or Postman) - they return an access token.  I'm trying to use that access token in the front end code to identify who the user is but I don't even know if I'm doing that right.

The weird part's that I'm not using a Bearer token in Postman but everything works perfectly fine.

So why won't it work in the browser?  Is my frontend code wrong?  If it is, I can't see what's wrong.

[image]

Here's my Frontend code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Upload extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedFile: null,
            id: null,
            email: ''
        };
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Inside componentDidMount()");
        let id = localStorage.getItem("id");
        let email = localStorage.getItem("email");
        console.log(id);
        console.log(email);
    }

    onFormSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.fileUpload(this.state.selectedFile);
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({ selectedFile: e.target.files[0] });
    }

    fileUpload(file) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("access_token").slice(13,-8);

        console.log(accessToken);
        console.log(this.state.id);
        console.log(this.state.email);
        formData.append('file', file);

        const headers = {
            'Contant-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
        }

        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/wall-of-fame', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
            headers: headers
        })
            .then(response => console.log(response))
            .catch(error => { console.error(error) });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form encType='multipart/form-data' id="login-form" className="form" onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                <input type="file" name="file" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
        );
    }

}

export default Upload;
```

Here's my FileUpload Controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class FileUploadController extends Controller {

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $filePath = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $email = Auth::user()->email;

        // dd($user_id, $email);

        $user = Auth::user();

        if($user) {
            $data = [
                'file_path' => $filePath,
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'email' => $email
            ];
            DB::table('cruskip.photos')->insert($data);
        }

        return response()->json($user);
    }
}
```

Here's my api.php file:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('signup', 'AuthController@signup');
    Route::post('wall-of-fame', 'FileUploadController@store');

    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'auth:api'
    ], function() {
        Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
        Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
        Route::get('wall-of-fame', 'FileUploadController@fileUpload');
    });
});
```

Here's my `create_users_table`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Here's my `create_photos_table`:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
class CreatePhotosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('photos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('file_path', 200);
            $table->string('email', 200);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger("user_id");
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('email')->references('email')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('photos');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you narrow down that code a bit? Where do you suspect is the issue?

Comment: @feedy I believe it's in my frontend code inside `fileUpload()` but not entirely sure

Comment: Could you show the body of the request taken from the dev tools and from postman. Let's see if there is any difference there. Also make sure you are not missing some header that postman includes by default

Comment: @feedy forgot to mention that the error I'm getting my logs is `ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object` but I just don't see how

Comment: Which line does this error refer to?

Comment: @feedy it's pointing to `$user_id = Auth::user()->id;` in the FileUpload Controller

Comment: Okay, first - put a breakpoint on that line and see what user() comes as

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218993/discussion-between-cloudyday-and-feedy).